Error encounter while installing dlib in virtual enverionment for face recognition library
I want to install face-recognition package but I got this error:
(testing2) C:\Users\WebPC-05\Style-Your-Hair>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\WebPC-05\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\testing2\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
          return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
        File "C:\Users\WebPC-05\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\testing2\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "C:\Users\WebPC-05\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\testing2\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have installed Python 3.11 in my pc globally and also install Python 3.11 in ver env to run the project but it said cmake not found. Bit I install cmake both in virtual env and locally, then I install python 3.9 in my virtual env and again install cmake and dlib but still got the same error. What should I do? I have already installed visual studio 2019 community also with desktop application c++ enabled.
